# Добавление UIButton в BaseViewController для отображения на всех UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Я вообще не разбираюсь в привязках одного UIViewController к другому , а также работе BaseViewController , но слышал что с помощью этого класса можно вставлять элементы на все UIViewController хотелось бы увидеть наглядный пример с кодом , например в BaseViewController мы вставляем UIButton и она отображается на всех UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально при создании проекта у тебя будет уже готовый класс ViewController.

У него из коробки будет свойство(проперти) self.view.
Это обычный родительский UIView.

На него ты и можешь положить любой объект класса UIView (А от него наследуются все UI элементы, в частности UIButton,UILabel ит.д).

код добавления

```
...
UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[but addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[but setFrame:CGRectMake(52, 252, 215, 40)];
[but setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[but setExclusiveTouch:YES];

 // Строка добавлениея на экран
[self.view addSubview:but];


-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{ 
  NSLog(@"you clicked on button %@", sender.tag);
}
```

Если же ты имел ввиду наследование.
То просто в интерфейсе определи проперти на некий UI
А во всех дочерних контроллеров инить их, задавай координаты и добавляй на экран